# Cannot write a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import csv
import operator
import sys

with open('countryInfo.csv','r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    result = sorted(reader, key = lambda d: float(d['population']),reverse = True)
 #   for row in result:
 #       print(row)
 #   for row in result:
 #      print(row['name'], row['capital'], row['population'])
writer = csv.DictWriter(open('country_simple_info.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8'), reader.fieldnames)
#with open("country_simple_info.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as csvoutfile:
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(result)
```

The goal of this code is to write a program that opens a `countryInfo.csv` file and extracts the country `name`, `capital` city and `population` from each row, then writes a new file named `country_simple_info.csv` with `country`, `capital` and `population` in each row, with the rows sorted by `population` size, largest first. The file has columns with other information such as `continent`, `languages`, etc. but the code should ignore those. In my code above, when I uncomment the `print` statements, the code can print the expected output - something in the following format:

```
country,capital,population 
China,Beijing,1330044000
India,New Delhi,1173108018
United States,Washington,310232863
.......
```

However, I cannot get the file to be written. Any ideas? And also, I am not allowed to use `pandas`.

Comment: Add a line that says writer.save() at the end and see if the file shows up then.

Comment: First, why are you not using a `with` statement for your output file, the way you are for your input file? That means you don’t close or flush the file, which is usually a bad thing.

Comment: Second, why are you using `reader.fieldnames` for your output CSV? If you only want 3 fields, you can’t pass a list of 8 (or whatever) fields, you have to pass just those 3. Otherwise, once you get things working, you’ll just end up making a sorted copy of the original CSV, with all the same columns.

Comment: Finally, what is the actual problem here? What does “I cannot get the file to be written” mean? You get an exception? An empty file? A non-empty but incorrect file? You can’t find the file at all in Explorer after the program runs? Or …?

Comment: I get an empty file usually.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('country_simple_info.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outputFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Using the "with open" statement will force the outputFile to close when it goes out of scope and thus saving the text written to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I run your code it says File "15.py", line 14, in <module>
    writer.writerow(result)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 155, in writerow

    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list

    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'